# How to change default pdf viewer for all users in command line

Tags: gnome, debian-squeeze, mime-types

I'm using Debian squeeze with Gnome Desktop for all my users. I have a group of machines to set up so that **all users** should use `xpdf` as a default viewer (rather than `evince`).

I want this set up to be done by command line (even better, using puppet).

I know about `xpg-mime` command, but the man page says that the default command should not be used as root.

I could manually tweak the `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` files, but I'm looking for a single command I could run to perform the setting without an editor interaction.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Linux defaults are set by editing text files. I doubt you can avoid that. You *can* however automate it. The following `sed` command will change `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` in the way that you need:

```
sed -i '/pdf/s/evince./xpdf./g'
```